# android OS のTCP再送タイムアウト値＆リトライ回数はどこに設定されていますか？

Tags: android, tcp

AndriodOSでのTCP再送タイムアウト値＆リトライ回数はどこに設定されていますか？
また設定ファイル等で存在するとして、書き換えることは可能でしょうか？

Windows、Linux(Posix)でのTCP関連設定値の場所は以下サイトにより分かっています。
https://tech-mmmm.blogspot.com/2015/03/ostcp.html

Answer (score 1):

> AndriodOSでのTCP再送タイムアウト値＆リトライ回数はどこに設定されていますか？

以下ディレクトリ下のファイルに設定されています。

```
 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/
```

> また設定ファイル等で存在するとして、書き換えることは可能でしょうか？

可能だと思います。
androidの場合はinit.rcでパラメータを書き換えるようです。※実際に確かめたわけではありません。
以下のように設定するのだと思います。

```
on init
    write /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries 5
```

init.rcの文法は以下で説明されています。

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md

実際にandroidデバイスのカーネルパラメータを書き換えるにはブートイメージを操作する必要があるのだと思います。
またIPの通信全体に影響を与えるため、広範なテストが必要と予想されますので、カーネルパラメータの書き換えは容易ではないと思います。